# Multiple Random numbers in a for loop in C#

Tags: c#, random, numbers

Programming novice here. I am trying to generate random coordinates for my points
But I am getting same numbers like (1,1) , (2,2) (5,5) etc

I put the random generator out of loop but that didn't help.

My Output looks like this

Point#0(4,4)
Point#1(8,8)
Point#2(9,9)
Point#3(1,1)
Point#4(0,0)

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace dotsGrids
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Grid grid = new Grid(9,5);            

            Console.WriteLine(grid.RenderGrid());

            Console.WriteLine("END.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    class Point
    {        
        public int x, y;
        public Point(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
    class Grid
    {
        static Random r = new Random();
        int size;
        int tempx, tempy;
        Point[] p;

        public Grid(int size,int numOfPoints)
        {
            this.size = size;
            p = new Point[numOfPoints];
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfPoints; i++)
            {
                tempx = r.Next(10);
                tempy = r.Next(10);
                p[i] = new Point(tempx,tempy);
            }
        }
        public string RenderGrid()
        {
            string s = " ";
            string sum = "";
            bool flag = true;
            for(int i=1;i<= size; i++)
            {
                s += " " + i;
            }
            s += "\n";
            for (int y=1;y<= size; y++)
            {
                s += y;
                for (int x = 1;x<= size; x++)
                {                    
                    for (int j = 0; j < p.Length; j++)
                    {                        
                        if (p[j].x == x && p[j].y == y)
                        {                            
                            if(p[j].x + p[j].y+"" != sum)//Prevent additional * if same coordinates
                            {
                                s += " *";
                            }
                            sum += p[j].x + p[j].y;
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if(flag) s += " -";
                    flag = true;
                }
                s += "\n";
            }
            s += "\n"; s += "\n"; s += "\n";
            for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
            {
                s += "Point#" + i + "(" + p[i].x + "," + p[i].x + ")";
                s += "\n";
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: VTC as Typo: `"Point#" + i + "(" + p[i].x + "," + p[i].x + ")"` has 2 `x` instead of `x`,'y`.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you need to change this line:

```
s += "Point#" + i + "(" + p[i].x + "," + p[i].x + ")";
```

to this:

```
s += "Point#" + i + "(" + p[i].x + "," + p[i].y + ")";
```

You were printing out the x-coordinate both times, instead of the x and the y coordinates.

Comment: Owmygod , I specificly cheked for that but my brain didn't register never the less. Sometimes we need somebody to point at things. Thanks